# LESS extend selector with nested classes properties

Tags: css, less

I am trying to automatically include the properties of a particular nested CSS class within another.

```
.lucid-TextField {
  color:red;

  &&-is-single-line{
      height: 1.75rem;
  }
}


.date-input input{
    &:extend(.lucid-TextField,
    .lucid-TextField.lucid-TextField-is-single-line ); 
}
```

It will include `lucid-TextField` but i get the alert `extend ' .lucid-TextField.lucid-TextField-is-single-line' has no matches`.

I tried some other approaches, this one fails the least. Is it possible at all to reference the `lucid-TextField`'s nested selectors that use &&?

Using @extend(.class all) is not the answer I am looking for - I simply want to pull all those properties into the new `.date-input input` selector.